# Labeling a curve in R using labcurve

Tags: r, plot, label

I'm getting back into working with R and I need to make a plot with numerous lines from three separate matrices. Currently, I'm using matplot and matlines to get the lines to plot. I want to label each line with its title centered horizontally and vertically on the line and I think there's a way to do it with labcurve. Unfortunately, I'm only finding the manual page for labcurve and no really clear examples of how to use it when I Google for it.

Can someone give me an example of using labcurve to place a label on a set of plotted lines produced similarly to how I described?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure (Kyle) you read the Hmisc::labcurve help page? It's got several nice examples.

Comment: I saw that, but I'm still missing something here. Say my matrix is named X and I have plotted one line per column for columns 1:m using matplot. Now if I try to use:

`labcurve(X,colnames(X), type="l")`

or

`labcurve(as.data.frame(X),colnames(X), type="l")`

I get

`Error in z$type : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Per FAQ: if you had  posted reproducible example data, we'd have caught this sooner.  RTFM:   It's not a failure of the `type` argument.  It's a failure somewhere else -- Reading the labcurve help: your "X" must be a list, of which EACH element is two vectors -- x and y data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using thigmophobe.labels from the plotrix package. It works like this:

`thigmophobe.labels(labelCoord.x,labelCoord.y,c("Title"),col="darkorange",font=2, cex=1)`

where labelCoord gives the x and y location where you want your title text to go.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at package directlabels (Poster price at user 2011) which is much more flexible than labcurve and works both with ggplot and lattice.

Comment: I'm trying to stick to regular plot - any suggestions there?